# how to use YouTubeBaseActivity in Fragment ,android

Tags: android, fragment

I useing the tabhost, I hope to use `YouTubeBaseActivity` in fragment 
what can I do?

```
public class yutubemain extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private YouTubePlayerView ytpv;
    private YouTubePlayer ytp;
    final String serverKey="AIzaSyBrNphq0HsQvQ5Rx4-Kenff-FhumNVMbnY"; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ytpv = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayer);
        ytpv.initialize(serverKey, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,
        YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Initialization Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
                                        YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasrestored) {
        ytp = player;

        Intent gt =getIntent();
        ytp.loadVideo(gt.getStringExtra("id"));
    }
}
```

this code change in fragment...

Comment: You can use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment to create your own Fragment and then use your favorite activity like AppCompatActivity or use YouTubeBaseActivity with a layout that contains a YouTubePlayer

Comment: Thank you Comment. but i don't understanded..
you can detailed for me?
Thank you.friend

Answer (score 1):

Use `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` if you are only playing a YouTube video in a single support.v4.app.Fragment rather than `YouTubeBaseActivity`.